# Problemas al mostrar dato relacionado en Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter, join

Resulta que tengo un problema quiero mostrar el nombre de tablas relacionadas con *inner join* en Codeigniter pero no me deja no se que estoy haciendo mal.

***Controlador***

```
public function consulta() {
    $asociados = array("tablaAsociados" => $this->asociados_modelo->listarAsociados());
    $this->load->view( 'consulta', $asociados );
}
```

***Modelo***

```
//consultamos los datos de asociados y mostraremos en tabla con datos relacionados
public function listarAsociados() {
    $this->db->order_by( 'id_asociado', 'asc' );
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join('paises', 'paises.code = asociados.pais');
    $query = $this->db->get( 'asociados' );
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

***Vista***

```
<?php foreach ($tablaAsociados as $tabla):?>
    <td><?php echo $tabla['nombre_primero'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tabla['apellido_primero'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tabla['dui'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tabla['nit'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tabla['municipio'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tabla['departamento'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tabla['pais'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Pero no me muestra el nombre del pais completo solo el valor de id del pais, de igual manera quiero mostrar el municipio y departamento relacionado.

***Captura de Listado de personas***
[image: Captura de Listado de personas]
De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: paises.code y asociados.pais son el mismo tipo de dato?

Comment: Si son del mismo tipo de datos en este caso varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas haciéndolo de una manera un poco extraña, así debería funcionar:

```
public function listarAsociados()
{
   $this->db->select('a.*,p.*');
   $this->db->from('asociados a');
   $this->db->join('paises p', 'p.code = a.pais');
   $this->db->order_by( 'a.id_asociado', 'asc' );
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

Mando a llamar todos los parámetros de ambas tablas porque no se exactamente cuales necesitas.

Comment: He agregado las lineas que me has enviado y sigue igual.

Comment: Obio porque en la vista tienes que mostrar el parámetro que quieres mostrar, como tienes el nombre del municipio en la tabla, si no vas a seguir mostrando el id.

Realiza un var_dump(); de la variable que estas pasando a la vista y ve el contenido que tiene esta y con eso vas a saber a que objeto acceder.

Comment: Excelente, al realizar el var_dump() me pude percatar el contenido y fue el cual me llevo a la solucion. Te agradezco por tu ayuda. Marco solucion a tu respuesta. Bendiciones

Comment: Excelente, que bueno que esa fue tu solucion. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola Aqui te dejo una propuesta provada seria revisar como esta la integridad de tus datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo

```
public function listarAsociados(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT a.*,p.nombrepais as pais FROM asociados a INNER JOIN pais p ON a.idpais=p.id ORDER BY a.id ASC");
        return $query->result();
    }
```